# Single Sign On in 2 different application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, single-sign-on

I have 2 different applications for the same client. One application is in `ASP.Net` and other one is in `MVC 3`. I want to implement SSO for that, I have never done that.
How can i approach this and are there some referral url or codes which i can refer for this?

Answer (score 0):

If both applications are in same domain, you can set domain level cookies. Like http://website1.sample.com and http://website2.sample.com . You can set cookie for ".sample.com" which can be shared across sub-domains.

Comment: domain is also different.